# Is there a verb I can use to convey the meaning "not doing something"?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, sentence

Is there a verb I can use to convey the meaning "not doing something"?

I want the sentence to be something like:

> "Application to _____ [*'not doing'*] course BSE...".

Please suggest how I can do this and any alternate form of the sentence which has a similar meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common phrase here would be

> Application for exemption from course BSE

This is used where a person is normally required to complete a course, or pass an exam, in order to achieve some wider qualification. . The person could, of course , simply refuse to go to the course, but in that case would not be awarded the qualification.

An example here is from the Institute and Faculty of Actuaries. To qualify as an actuary, it is normally necessary to pass a series of exams. However students can apply for [exemption](https://www.actuaries.org.uk/studying/exam-exemptions/how-apply-exemption) for some examinations which means they can still qualify as actuaries without taking those particular exams. Of course, exemption is only approved if the student can show that he has already demonstrated his knowledge of the subject of the exam. If, for example, he has a statistics degree, he may apply for exemption from the statistics exam CT3.

Comment: It would work in a case where let's say some one has to do a course for sure and for some reason he doesn't want to do it?

Comment: Yes. It works where  some one has to do the course, but does not want to do it for some reason, but still wants to be treated as if he had done it. So if all students or employees have to do something but he doesn't want to do it, and yet  he still wants to be  treated as  a student or employee, just as if he had done it,  he can apply for exemption.  Is this what you mean?.

Answer (score 0):

In the academia context you are writing, the word '*offer*' is often used for courses a person is taking or doing. So the negative form would be '*unoffered*' and your sentence might read something like this:

> "Application to *unoffered* course BSE...".

Comment: "Offer" and "take" are not equivalent, and neither are "unoffered" and "untaken". You offer me a course, and I then decide to take it. They are logically connected but do not express the same action. Similarly, just because a store sells (=offers) products, does not express the same as you buying (=taking) a product.